# Правильно ли отдаю Last-Modified

Tags: php

Друзья привет.У меня есть такой код

```
<?php ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'On');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', '1');
include('dbcon.inc.php');
mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_LOGIN,DB_PASS) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die (mysql_error());
$sql="SELECT msg,date,titlenews,fototn,foton FROM msgs ORDER BY id DESC";
$users = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
/* $num=mt_rand(2000,10000);
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time()-$num)); */
?>
```

Ласт модифайд закоментирован как вы заметили.
Вопрос: Когда Я внесу новую информацию на страницу,раскоментирую этот код обновлю страницу а после опять его закоментирую.Заголовки ведь уйдут,и тем самым я не буду обманывать поисковик.Нормальный способ?

Comment: Налицо непонимание что такое HTTP-заголовки :)

Comment: очень хочется послать тебя умник!да я недопонимаю и то что я недопонимаю я пытаюсь узнать на форумах!и вот такие бараны как ты не могут ничего нормально ответить а лишь оставляют самодовольные посты.

Answer (score 1):

А для чего это все? Делайте как хотите, поскольку не понятно для чего это...

Почему бы не оставить `header` раскомментированным, просто сделать запрос в склю на последнюю добавленную запись и дату туда вписать из возвращенного ответа. По-моему это будет лучшим решением.